# Не применяются стили к тексту

Tags: html, css

Вот есть такой банер:
не знаю почему, но стили к тексту не применяются. Ни цвет, ни шрифт, ничего. помогите пожалуйста)

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: unisans; 
    src: url(assets/unisans.ttf); 
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: crimson;
}


}
.headertxt {
    font-family: unisans;
    color: white;

    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
     <div class="content-banner">
        <span class="headertxt">НЕ КОПИРУЙ!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: unisans; 
    src: url(assets/unisans.ttf); 
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: crimson;
}



.headertxt {
    font-family: unisans;
    color: white;

    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
     <div class="content-banner">
        <span class="headertxt">НЕ КОПИРУЙ!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Лишняя скобка в стилях

Comment: Извиняюсь за  тупой вопрос ,_,  вечером сидел полусонный, тупил, не заметил)